# GCLOUD: Getting the name of a snapshot list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

#### Question:

How do i get a Value from a list into a Variable (String) in Gcloud?

#### Wanted:

I need to get the name of the Snapshot. With a Powershell list i would just do:

```
$os_disk_snapshot= (gcloud compute snapshots list --limit=1 --filter="creationTimestamp.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)='$date'" --filter="sourceDisk=$source_disk"").name
```

But this doesn't work.
The following just gives me a list with the parameters name,disk_size_gb, sourcedisk and status. But i only need the name.

```
gcloud compute snapshots list --limit=1 --filter="creationTimestamp.date('%Y-%m-%d', Z)='$date'" --filter="sourceDisk=$source_disk""
```

Greetings and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `--format "value(name)"` in the command to get only name.

> --format "value(name)"

Read more about gcloud Global Flags [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference?hl=zh-cn#--format)